# How can I run a model multiple times changing the parameter value in pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo, gurobi

I am working with a MIP model with multiple parameters and I'd like to test different scenarios (with different parameter values).

I've created a df with the parameter values that need to be changed and did a loop where the values are supposed to change but they are not.

```
for s in model.s:
model.Pmill == model.Smill[s].value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `=` instead of `==`.

One equals assigns a value, while two values compare.
What your code does is just comparing both values every iteration without using the result.

```py
for s in model.s:
    model.Pmill = model.Smill[s].value
```